# How to deter users from making many accounts to skew site functions?

Tags: users, email-accounts

My site requires a unique email address to link to the site account, of course, but does anyone have suggestions as to ways to deter people from using throwaway email addresses to make many accounts?

I ask because in instances like hosting giveaways or voting up shared content I would prefer people weren't able to easily skew votes/entries in their favor, but I cannot think of a single way how.

Comment: See [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6754/when-using-email-as-login-name-what-precautions-should-i-take-for-registration) and [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/people-sign-up-to-my-website-but-they-keep-entering-invalid-email-addresses-the) related question. Aside from confirming their email address via an emailed confirmation link, you can check that they're signing up with and confirming using a unique IP address that isn't associated with another email address. The drawback is that might preclude users from large organizations, colleges, etc...

Comment: ...since their networks might use shared public IP addresses. You can also send another confirmation link later on, since many probably won't recheck throwaway accounts after a period of time.

Comment: And this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21130/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-creating-multiple-accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an email confirmation link with a 15+ minute delay on register. May deter some users, but would prevent some throw away email services.